# "EOFError: Ran out of input" Keep getting this error while trying to pickle

Tags: python, pickle, eof

I am writing a quiz program. I am trying to give the user the opportunity to write and add their own question. I have wrote functions to ask and add questions. I am trying to pickle
the list of questions so I can auto load new questions anytime somebody adds one.

This is the code I am using to load the pickled file.

```
sciIn = open('sciList.txt','rb')
sci = pickle.load(sciIn)
sciIn.close()
```

I have this code in the function that adds questions.

```
sciOut = open("sciList.txt",'wb')
sci.append(dicQ)
pickle.dump(sci, sciOut)
sciOut.close()
```

When I run the code I get EOFError: Ran out of input which points to the loading of the pickle. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using Python 3. Thanks for your help!

full code
http://pastebin.com/HEp0KhRA

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable code that reproduces the problem. I don't think there's any problem in the lines of code quoted here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be doing the pickling right, but maybe working from an empty file at some point… and if you do this on the load, you can get odd `EOF` errors.  Also, if you hand-edited the file in any way (or didn't store the data with pickle), then you can also get `EOF` Errors on loading.

This works (but note I'm storing questions as a dictionary).

```
>>> import pickle
>>> sciIn = open('sciList.txt', 'rb') # has 2 pickled dict entries already
>>> sci = pickle.load(sciIn)
>>> sci
{'what is a dog?': 'a dog', 'what kind of parrot is that?': 'a dead parrot'}
>>> sciIn.close()
>>> 
>>> sciOut = open('sciList.txt', 'wb')
>>> sci["what's your favorite colour?"] = "python"  
>>> pickle.dump(sci, sciOut)
>>> sciOut.close()
```

From your code, it looks like you were pickling a list instead of a dictionary (hence the append to add the new question).  The above should work for a list, as well, and you'd just append as you have done in your code.  Regardless, if you are trying to read from an object from an empty file with pickle, you'll get an `EOF` Error -- however, if you start your code from a file that was created by pickling an empty list, you shouldn't get an `EOF` Error.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> sciIn = open('sciList2.txt', 'rb') # has a pickled empty list
>>> sci = pickle.load(sciIn)
>>> sci
['what is a dog?', 'what kind of parrot is that?']
>>> sciIn.close()
>>> 
>>> sciOut = open('sciList2.txt', 'wb')
>>> sci.append("what's your favorite color?")
>>> pickle.dump(sci, sciOut)
>>> sciOut.close()
```