# EOFError: ran out of input. Getting this error when trying to pickle.loads from a socket

Tags: python, sockets, numpy, pickle

I have a `numpy ndarray` that I'm trying to send via socket connection. When I try to load it on the server, using `pickle.loads` I get `EOFError: ran out of input`.

## client.py

```
import numpy as np
import socket, pickle
import struct
HOST = "192.168.143.xxx"
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
centers = np.zeros((100, 43919))
packet = pickle.dumps(centers)
length = struct.pack('>I', len(packet))
packet = length + packet
s.send(packet)

data = s.recv(8192)
data_new = pickle.loads(data)
s.close()
print ('Received', data_new)
```

## server.py

```
import socket, pickle, numpy as np
import struct
HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)

while 1:
    L = np.zeros((100, 43919))
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connected with ', addr)
    buf = b''
    while len(buf) < 4:
        buf += conn.recv(4 - len(buf))

    length = struct.unpack('>I', buf)[0]
    print(length)
    data = conn.recv(length)
    if not data: break
    M = pickle.loads(data) # HERE IS AN ERROR, the same as np.loads(...)
    L += M
    data_out = pickle.dumps(L)
    conn.sendall(data_out)
    conn.close()

s.close()
```

I've tried reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726495/pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-when-recv-from-a-socket), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-with-my-python-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983082/eoferror-ran-out-of-input-keep-getting-this-error-while-trying-to-pickle) but nothing helps.

I'm using Python 3.4.

EDIT:

The exact error is:

```
File server.py, line 30, in <module>:
M = pickle.loads(data) #HERE IS AN ERROR
EOFError: Ran out of input.
```

Comment: `recv(n)` returns **at most** `n` bytes. Also, you are using an hard-coded number (8192): how can you be sure that your object fits in 8192 bytes?

Comment: Probably I don't (I don't know yet how to change it) but my code fails before it gets to that point, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, something is not adding up :) Your question is about `pickle.loads` and there is only one `pickle.loads(...)` line in your code. So why do you say that it's failing earlier? What error are you getting?

Comment: No, there are two `pickle.loads(...)` lines in my code. The error is in the server part of the code - it's marked by a comment.

Comment: The exact error is:

`File server.py, line 30, in <module>:
M = pickle.loads(data) #HERE IS AN ERROR
EOFError: Ran out of input.`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Not being familiar with numpy, I didn't know that `numpy.loads` is the same as `pickle.loads` -- anyhow, be sure to send all the data from the client (e.g. using `sendall`) and be sure to receive all of it (e.g. using a loop similar to `while len(buf) < 4:`)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's the same with either `pickle.loads` or `np.loads`. Thanks for the other advices.

Comment: By the way: [Python pickle is not intended to be secure](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/03/exploiting-pickle/): anyone who can connect to this socket can mess with your program.

Comment: And when I say, [pickle is not secure](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/03/exploiting-pickle/), what I mean is: anyone who can connect to this socket can make your program run arbitrary commands including opening a remote shell. So, really seriously think twice before deploying this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conn.recv(length)` does not necessarily read `length` bytes, if there are less than that number available. You need to loop until you have enough.

See [When does socket.recv(recv_size) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7174927/243712)

```
data = b''
l = length
while l > 0:
    d = sock.recv(l)
    l -= len(d)
    data += d
```

There is a similar issue in your code that uses `.send()`, although in that case there is an easy fix: just use `.sendall()` as you do in the other place.

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly what to do? I'm a python and socket connection newbie, so I don't know much about it.

Comment: @poolie: you should also add a note about `send` vs `sendall`